# Force HTML table width by Only Having <td witdth>

Tags: html, css

I would like to force my HTML table to have a width by only having  for each column.

What I have right now is the code below. I've removed some of the other code that doesn't apply. It is not overflowing properly and the table is only being rendered at 100% width of my screen.

```css
#example_table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.zui-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.zui-scroller {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="zui-wrapper">
  <div class="zui-scroller">
    <table id="example_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 75px;">Col1</th>
          <th style="width: 50px;">Col2</th>
          <th style="width: 200px;">Col3</th>
          <th style="width: 70px;">Col4</th>
          <th style="width: 70px;">Col5</th>
          <th style="width: 70px;">Col6</th>
          <th style="width: 70px;">Col7</th>
          <th style="width: 100px;">Col8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Ex1</td>
          <td>Ex2</td>
          <td>Ex3</td>
          <td>Ex4</td>
          <td>Ex5</td>
          <td>Ex6</td>
          <td>Ex7</td>
          <td>Ex8</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried adding the width="xx" to each of the rows. I do not wish to use width="xx" under the #example_table CSS because I have a javascript code that hides some rows, and when that is done, the table examples to that same width.

I've also tried many different CSS combinations of overflow in the different classes/IDs. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Do you want a horizontal scrollable table?

Comment: Instead of specifying table width to (for example 1700px) I want the table width to be set by what the <th> tag sets. In theory if the table is large enough to go over the screen, then yeah it would need to be scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<colgroup>` to precise the width of the columns.
Here is an example:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.tg th {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 700px">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 75px">
    <col style="width: 50px">
    <col style="width: 200px">
    <col style="width: 70px">
    <col style="width: 70px">
    <col style="width: 70px">
    <col style="width: 70px">
    <col style="width: 100px">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
    <th>Col5</th>
    <th>Col6</th>
    <th>Col7</th>
    <th>Col8</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ex1</td>
    <td>Ex2</td>
    <td>Ex3</td>
    <td>Ex4</td>
    <td>Ex5</td>
    <td>Ex6</td>
    <td>Ex7</td>
    <td>Ex8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the columns are still not the required width. e.g. column 3 is 171, not 200